# Change layout of an existig view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I have downloaded a library from Github - https://github.com/riyagayasen/Android_accordion_view and added it as a module to my project. 
I want to change the layout of the view, because the default one doesn't quite suit my design. By default it looks like this: https://pp.userapi.com/c855132/v855132038/18192/AJnXb6Z7l4c.jpg; I want it look like this: https://pp.userapi.com/c855132/v855132038/18178/VyKEhn6ERuk.jpg; but all i have achieved is this: https://pp.userapi.com/c848416/v848416709/1602db/3JjKU9eMj0g.jpg.

It is clear that I have to change the layout of the AccordionView.

The path to the layout XML is Android_accordion_view/easyaccordion/src/main/res/layout/accordion.xml 
I am sure that AccordionView uses exactly this layout because there is a method in AccordionView.java that inflates this XML as a layout:

```
private void initializeViews(Context context) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //here it happens
        LinearLayout accordionLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.accordion, null); 


        partition = accordionLayout.findViewById(R.id.partition);
        heading = (TextView) accordionLayout.findViewById(R.id.heading);
        paragraph = (RelativeLayout) accordionLayout.findViewById(R.id.paragraph_layout);
        dropdownImage = (ImageView) accordionLayout.findViewById(R.id.dropdown_image);
        dropupImage = (ImageView) accordionLayout.findViewById(R.id.dropup_image);
        headingLayout = (LinearLayout) accordionLayout.findViewById(R.id.heading_layout);
        paragraph.removeAllViews();

        int i;
        children = new View[getChildCount()];
        for (i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            children[i] = getChildAt(i);
        }
        removeAllViews();
        for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            paragraph.addView(children[i]);
        }


        paragraphBottomMargin = ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) paragraph.getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin;
        paragraphTopMargin = ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) paragraph.getLayoutParams()).topMargin;

        addView(accordionLayout);


    }
```

The problem is that if I change accordion.xml, nothing actually changes when I add the AccordionView to my fragment's layout, and that's super weird.

I assume that I have somehing wrong in Gradle dependences or somewhere near it, but I can't figure it out.

That is the xml that I want to change the default layout to.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/accordion_background"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/heading_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/favourite_checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:button="@drawable/star_checkbox"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/heading"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dropup_image"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/favourite_checkBox"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/favourite_checkBox"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/favourite_checkBox" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dropdown_image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/favourite_checkBox"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/favourite_checkBox"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/favourite_checkBox" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/partition"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/paragraph_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:visibility="visible">

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Yes, I understand that the heading layout is LinearLayout by default, but even if I change the dropdown icon size in the default layout, it stays the same when I use the view.

So my question is: how can I make the layout above appear when I use the view?

I will provide any of my code by your request. 
Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Calamity, can you explain a little better? You want your layout to look like the one you downloded? If yes, then you simply need to adjust some of the view attributes. Please share your code.

Comment: Hello. 
I extended my question so it should be clearer.